# How to filter results in autocomplete before displaying?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery-ui autocomplete to retrieve some results from the server. I want to filter the results on the client side based on a client side function. How do I do that?

Here is the pseudocode of what I want:

```
function is_valid_value(item) {
  // returns true if item is valid, false otherwise
}

$( "#some-text-field" ).autocomplete({
      source: $.get('url/path/to/autocomplete.json?term=abc', function(data) {
          // item is an element in the data collection
          return data.filter(item) {
            return is_valid_value(item);
          }
        })
      }
```

I know this doesn't work on multiple levels - I don't have the actual term to pass in, and I also get a syntax error - Unexpected token `{` on the line `return data.filter(item) {`. I also looked at `ajaxSuccess` which seems to be used mainly to alert the user of successful completion - I don't know if it can be used to filter data and return it.

Comment: in jquery ui API you can find:`$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});`

Answer (score 0):

I used a different solution that sent enough data to the server to filter on the server:

```
$("#some-text-field").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
              url: '/path/to/autocomplete',
              dataType: "json",
              data: {
                term: request.term,
                blocked: blocked_results(), //a function that returns the results to block 
               },
               success: function(data) {
                 response(data);
               }
           })
});
```

The server then sends back only valid results, so there is no filtering needed on the client.